# lining up printfs to look nice and line them up

Tags: c, format, printf, spacing

How in the world do you format this for things to line up, ive tried everything, nothing changes?!

```
printf("N Count\n");
printf("---- ------ \n");

for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_ELEMENTS ; i++)
{
    count = getOccur(arr, MAX_ELEMENTS, arr[i]);
    printf("%1d %1d\n", arr[i], count);
}
```

I've tried tabbing, spacing, those % signs with the numbers for the last one, it wont change from this

```
N  Count
----- ---
       1      1
       2      1
       3      1
```

Driving me crazy! I dont get it! lol

EDIT WHOLE PROGRAM NEW QUESTION!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 10


int getOccur(int a[], int num_elements, int value);
void printArr(int a[], int num_elements);

int main()
{
    int arr[MAX_ELEMENTS];
    int trim[MAX_ELEMENTS];
    int count, target, i;
    int j, k, temp;

    for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_ELEMENTS ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a variable for the array: ");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (j = 1 ; j <= MAX_ELEMENTS-1 ; j++)
    {
        for(k = 0 ; k <= MAX_ELEMENTS-2 ; k++)
        {
            if(arr[k] > arr[k+1])
            {
                temp = arr[k];
                arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                arr[k+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%4s %6s\n", " N ", "Count");
    printf("%4s %6s\n", "----", "------");

    for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_ELEMENTS ; i++)
    {
        count = getOccur(arr, MAX_ELEMENTS, arr[i]);
        printf("%3d %4d\n", arr[i], count);
    }
}

int getOccur(int a[], int tally, int value)
{
    int i;
    tally = 0;

    for( i = 0 ; i < MAX_ELEMENTS ; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == value)
        {
            ++tally;
        }
    }

    return(tally);

}

void printArr(int a[], int amount)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < amount ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided won't give the output you've provided!

Comment: Well I guess the numbers are fine for the time being, but how do I line up the dashes and N and Count?

Comment: Sorry cant seem to get that piece in the middle to be recognized as code. Not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%4s %6s\n", " N ", "Count");
printf("%4s %6s\n", "----", "------");

for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_ELEMENTS ; i++)
{
  count = getOccur(arr, MAX_ELEMENTS, arr[i]);
  printf("%4d %6d\n", arr[i], count);
}
```

That *should* line everything up.

**EDIT**

In response to the question in the comments, my approach would be to first find all the unique values in `arr` and save them to a different array (call it `unique`).  Then you'd walk through the `unique` array in your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < uniqueCount; i++)
{
  count = getOccur(arr, MAX_ELEMENTS, unique[i]);
  printf("%4d %6d\n", unique[i], count);
}
```

As for finding unique elements, the brute force method would be something like

```
size_t uniqueCount = 0;
int unique[MAX_SIZE];   // needs to be same size as original array in case
                        // all values are unique

for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
{
  size_t j = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < uniqueCount; j++)
    if (arr[i] == unique[j])
      break;

  if (j == uniqueCount)
    unique[uniqueCount++] = arr[i];
}
```

For each element in the original array, we scan the (initially empty) `unique` array.  If we don't find the value of `a[i]` in the `unique` array, we add it and increment `uniqueCount`.

Note that this method is pretty inefficient and will perform poorly as MAX_ELEMENTS gets large.  Better solutions are available, but you sound like you're still at the bottom of the learning curve, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Sherifftwinkie: sure, what?

Comment: Alright I am going to edit my OP to contain my entire program but I will ask the question here. When I run my program and do all my inputting and what not, it prints out what i inputed with their occurrences next to them. Now if i type in like "2" 6 times it will print "2" 6 times and tell me it occured 6 times, i only want it to tell me once, how do i do that?!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. The first column you have four - so the minimum width is four, the next column has size - so minimum width is 6 as specified in the format string. see [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) manual page

```
printf("N    Count\n");
printf("---- ------ \n");

for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_ELEMENTS ; i++)
{
  count = getOccur(arr, MAX_ELEMENTS, arr[i]);
  printf("%4d %6d\n", arr[i], count);
}
```

**EDIT**

Edited first `printf`

Comment: I dont understand what the width actually represents, does it mean like 1234 and 123456? Also how do I get the first 2 printf statements in place?

Comment: Press the space bar! See above